# Fast search for text in files in a directory in unix?

Tags: unix, full-text-search

Is there a good solution for performing searches similar to

```
find . -name "*.*" | xargs grep "some text"
```

but with much faster search, due to offline indexing. Support for wildcards or light regular expressions would be nice, but even raw text search that could run very fast due to offline preprocessing would be great.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562297/fast-search-in-compressed-text-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be overkill for your purposes, but [Beagle](http://beagle-project.org/Main_Page) allows you to perform very fast searches of local files. It's usually marketed as a desktop application, but in fact it is just a daemon that can respond to requests from the command-line using [beagle-query](http://beagle-project.org/Searching_Data#beagle-query).

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a great and fast option

```
grep -rl "string" /path
```

Answer (score 0):

[Recoll](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/) has a decent indexing mechanism for local files, but it comes with a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

grep -Ri --include="*.xml" TEXT /directory/

- this searches 'TEXT' text in all xml files in particular directory, but it may not be as fast as you expect

Answer (score -4):

Python

```
from __future__ import print_function
import glob
for name in glob.glob('*.*'):
    with open(name,'r') as aFile:
        for n, text in enumerate(aFile):
            if 'some text' in text:
                print( name, n, text )
```

You have a very complete regular expression library in the `re` module.

Rather than print the results, you could create a `shelve` database or some other index structure.

Comment: This won't be any faster than `grep` (in fact, its likely to be much slower). The OP is looking for something that precomputes indices, so that lookups don't have to actually read in the data at search-time.

Comment: @Adrian Petrescu: have you measured?  This is pretty fast.

Comment: It still has to load and read in every single file, so that lower bound is there even if matching the regex took 0 time. A precomputed index doesn't involve opening the files you're searching over at all, which I think is what he's getting at.

Comment: This should be used to "precompute" the index.